# Proof Verification: Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Theorem: For G a finite group and H a subgroup of G, the number of elements of H divides number of elements of G.

Let $|G| = n$ and $|H|=m$

Then we know that the distinct left cosets of H partition G and since a bijection exists between H and any of its left cosets, the order of the left cosets equals the order of H. i.e.

$|H|=|a_i H| = m$ where $a_i$ are distinct left cosets of H.

Then, the union of the distinct left cosets of H equal G and thus:

$|G| = r|H|$ where r is the number of distinct left cosets of H.

Then:
$n= rm$ and then by division algorithm, this implies remainder is zero and thus $m|n$ or equivalently, $|H|||G|$

Can anyone please tell me if the proof is correct? Any suggestions to make it better?

Comment: I would add the reason the union of distinct cosets of $H$ is equal to $G$ because of the equivalent relation on $G$ by the cosets. Equivalence relation = partition of distinct cells. Otherwise, I see no problem.

Comment: Ok! Thank you. Also, is my usage of division algorithm in this proof correct?

Comment: yes, but i would for example add at the top, that in order to prove $|H|$ is a divisor of $|G|$, you want to show that $r=0$ in $|G|=q|H|+r$ where $0\le r<q$ by the division algorithm, but that is just taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the comments from @Kam

Your proof assumes it has already been shown that
 1. The cosets partition $G$
 2. There is a bijection from each coset to $H$
If so, the proof is fine, otherwise you need to prove them (and you don't need to use an equivalence relation to do #1).

Delete the discussion of the division algorithm. The statement $a|b$ is defined to mean there is a $c$ such that $ac=b$ and you have already done that.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I've already proved that cosets partition G and there exists a bijection from a coset of H to H :)